# Real analysis = $\lim_{q\to 1}(\text{q-deformed analysis})$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can conventional analysis by replaced by q-deformed analysis such that all theorems that have a computable meaning (which don't depend on the Axiom of Choice) can be recovered in the $q\to 1$ limit? This would have the advantage that real analysis can then be done without having to define real numbers.

Comment: In how far would that be an advantage? Defining the real numbers isn't so hard (now that we know how), so what would be gained?

Comment: @DanielFischer That's the old debate about  constructivism, finitism etc. My personal view is that when I do physics, I consider some system that for all we know has only a finite number of degrees of freedom and yet we need to appeal to some uncountable set to even define some mathematical operations needed to compute its properties. This suggests that the reals were not actually needed. Simply making things discrete doesn't work well in practice, but q-deformed analysis, which is a more sophisticated way to go about things, may work better.

Comment: I see. Thankfully, I don't do physics ;)

Comment: What is $q$-deformed analysis ? The [$q$ analogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) are something very special, in some way trying to generalize some formulas valid in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ to some function field, say [$\mathbb{C}((x))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_ring_of_formal_power_series)